# An empty file after sending file to tcp server

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcpclient

I try to sort out this code i have manage do make it works but then wen i try to send the file from the client to the server then the file its come empty and with no extension.
well i have try some examples from internet but i can not get it work correctly

this is my code

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Visible = False
    RECIBE()
End Sub
Public Sub RECIBE()

    Dim CLIENTE As TcpClient
    Dim TAMAÑOBUFFER As Integer = 1024
    Dim ARCHIVORECIBIDO As Byte() = New Byte(TAMAÑOBUFFER - 1) {}
    Dim BYTESRECIBIDOS As Integer
    Dim FIN As Integer = 0
    Dim SERVIDOR As New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8080)
    SERVIDOR.Start()
    While FIN = 0
        Dim NS As NetworkStream = Nothing
        Try
            Dim ACEPTA As String = "ACEPTA EL FICHERO ENTRANTE"
            Dim TITULO As String = "FICHERO ENTRANTE"
            Dim BOTONES As MessageBoxButtons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo
            Dim RESULTADO As DialogResult
            If SERVIDOR.Pending Then
                CLIENTE = SERVIDOR.AcceptTcpClient
                NS = CLIENTE.GetStream
                RESULTADO = MessageBox.Show(ACEPTA, TITULO, BOTONES)
                If RESULTADO = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                    Dim FICHERORECIBIDO As String = Nothing
                    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                        FICHERORECIBIDO = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
                        Label1.Text = FICHERORECIBIDO
                    End If
                    If FICHERORECIBIDO <> String.Empty Then
                        Dim TOTALBYTESRECIBIDOS As Integer = 0
                        Dim FS As New FileStream(FICHERORECIBIDO, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
                        While (AYUDAENLINEA(BYTESRECIBIDOS, NS.Read(ARCHIVORECIBIDO, 0, ARCHIVORECIBIDO.Length))) > 0
                            FS.Write(ARCHIVORECIBIDO, 0, BYTESRECIBIDOS)
                            TOTALBYTESRECIBIDOS = TOTALBYTESRECIBIDOS + BYTESRECIBIDOS
                        End While
                        FS.Close()
                    End If
                    NS.Close()
                    CLIENTE.Close()
                    'SERVIDOR.Stop()
                    MsgBox("DESCARGA FINALIZADA")
                    FIN = 1
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End While
    SERVIDOR.Stop()
    Button1.Visible = True
End Sub
Private Shared Function AYUDAENLINEA(Of T)(ByRef OBJETIVO As T, VALOR As T)
    OBJETIVO = VALOR
    Return VALOR
End Function


End Class
```

client side sender
This is my code

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName


    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim TAMAÑOBUFFER As Integer = 1024
    Try
        Dim CLIENTE As New TcpClient(TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text)
        Dim NS As NetworkStream = CLIENTE.GetStream
        Dim FS As New FileStream(TextBox1.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim PAQUETES As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling(CDbl(FS.Length) / CDbl(TAMAÑOBUFFER)))
        Dim LONGITUDTOTAL As Integer = CInt(FS.Length)
        Dim LONGITUDPAQUETEACTUAL As Integer = 0
        Dim CONTADOR As Integer = 0
        For I As Integer = 0 To PAQUETES - 1
            If LONGITUDTOTAL > TAMAÑOBUFFER Then
                LONGITUDPAQUETEACTUAL = TAMAÑOBUFFER
                LONGITUDTOTAL = LONGITUDTOTAL - LONGITUDPAQUETEACTUAL
            Else
                LONGITUDPAQUETEACTUAL = LONGITUDTOTAL
            End If
            Dim ENVIARBUFFER As Byte() = New Byte(LONGITUDPAQUETEACTUAL - 1) {}
            FS.Read(ENVIARBUFFER, 0, LONGITUDPAQUETEACTUAL)
            NS.Write(ENVIARBUFFER, 0, CInt(ENVIARBUFFER.Length))

        Next
        FS.Close()
        NS.Close()
        CLIENTE.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I just forget to mention i have convert this code from c#

Comment: Just by looking at it the code seems fine. Place [**breakpoints**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx) in your code and step through it to see what executes and whatnot. -- Also, can you show us the sender's code?

Comment: @VisualVincent i just edit and post the sending code

Comment: Both codes look fine... I'll try it in a while when I get home.

Comment: @VisualVincent i have place an breakpoint at the sender on the line FS.Read(ENVIARBUFFER, 0, LONGITUDPAQUETEACTUAL) and until there i can not find any thing wrong

Comment: i have look at the lines on the bottom and i can read canwrite=false

Comment: Sorry, ignore the last comment if you saw it before I deleted it. `CanWrite = False` because you open the `FS` stream using `FileAccess.Read`, but that's okay on the sender's side since it only reads from the file.

Comment: @VisualVincent well i have try to insert more breakpoints but i can not find the problem because the file it apears but with 0 bits and with out any extension

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code and tested it. It works perfectly.

Comment: @VisualVincent well here its works but wen i try to send the file its come empty and with out any extension

Comment: It doesn't for me. I tried sending images and they arrive as they should and I can view them. Are you sure there's no other code modifying your variables?

Comment: The file is created when you call `New FileStream(<file here>, ...)`, so if anything's bugged it's the `FileStream`. What .NET Framework version are you targeting? And are you targeting the regular framework or CE (Compact Edition)? What IDE (for example Visual Studio) are you using and what version of it?

Comment: @VisualVincent    sorry for late return , i has on working On Rally Monchique 2017 make videos , i just return home now. the framework is 2.0

Comment: and the visual studio i work with 2012 version

Comment: Still works in .NET 2.0 for me. I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Well my interest on it is because i want a code that make me able to connect with server and wen they rights something on chat for example atack then they will atack the chose people on the chat and the heal points will down and the fuel to

Comment: i have try with a vb.net chat but i only can connect with one people at time

Comment: @VisualVincent i have made a new post here

Comment: @VisualVincent with other example but i can not find the way to know the variable of message

Comment: @VisualVincent link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621778/how-can-i-know-the-variable-from-message-received-on-server-or-client-vb-net