# How can i know the variable from message received on server or client vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can i know the variable from message received on server or client vb.net

i have try with this Multi-Threading chat client and server
but i can not find the way to know the variable of the message received
Message receive well what i mean with message received is:
i liked to be able to know the message and then compare if the message is = "atack" then 
I have try like this there is no errors but nothing happen wen it receive the atack word 
this is what i have try

```
Dim keywords() As String = {"atack"}
    If keywords.Count(Function(w) rtbServer.Text.ToLower.Contains(w)) > 0 Then
        'at least one string from keywords was found
        MsgBox("You Are Under Atack")

        health = health - 1
        fuel = fuel - 1
        Label6.Text = health
        Label8.Text = fuel
        rtbServer.Clear()
        Label6.Text = health
        Label8.Text = fuel
    End If
```

this is my code for form communicator

```
Public Class frmCommunicator
Dim user As String = Nothing
Dim disconected As String = Nothing
Dim disconnSock As String = Nothing
Dim sendall As String = Nothing
Dim exclude_sock As Integer
Dim new_sock As Integer
Dim privSock As Integer
Dim privSock2 As Integer
Dim privSock3 As Integer
Dim privString As String = Nothing
Dim list As String = Nothing
Dim list1 As String = Nothing
Dim list2 As String = Nothing
Dim countListItems As Integer
Dim health = 100
Dim fuel = 100
Dim cristaisdequartzo = 0
Dim ouro = 0
Dim prata = 0
Dim diamantes = 0
Public Sub sendPriv()

    Server.Send(privSock2, "@code1847@" & privString & "   " & CStr(privSock3))
    Server.Send(privSock3, "@code1847@" & privString & "   " & CStr(privSock2))
    privSock3 = Nothing
    privSock2 = Nothing
    privString = Nothing

End Sub
Public Sub dodaj_korisnika()
    ListBox1.Items.Add(user + "   " + CStr(privSock))
    countListItems += 1
    user = Nothing
End Sub
Public Sub izbrisi_korisnika()
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If ListBox1.Items.Item(i).ToString = disconected & "   " & disconnSock Then
            ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    disconected = Nothing
End Sub
Public Sub senditall()
    serverSendToAllConnected2("", sendall)
    sendall = Nothing
End Sub
Public Sub usersUpdate()
    serverSendToAllConnected3("", sendall)
End Sub
Public Sub userLeave()
    serverSendToAllConnected4("", sendall)
End Sub
Private Sub serverSendToAllConnected4(ByVal User As String, ByVal Message As String, Optional ByVal ExceptSock As Integer = -1)
    If isArraySafe(InUse) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To InUse.Length - 1

            If Not (i = ExceptSock) Then
                If InUse(i) Then

                    list2 = ""
                    For b As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 ' nema potrebe izvrtjeti sve korisnike ponovo i za one kojima su veæ uploadani
                        ' OVAJ DIO JE ZA NOVOULOGIRANE KORISNIKE
                        list2 = list2 & ListBox1.Items.Item(b).ToString + vbCrLf
                    Next
                    Server.Send(i, "@code1840@" & list2)

                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    list2 = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub serverSendToAllConnected3(ByVal User As String, ByVal Message As String, Optional ByVal ExceptSock As Integer = -1)
    If isArraySafe(InUse) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To InUse.Length - 1

            If Not (i = ExceptSock) Then
                If InUse(i) Then
                    If new_sock = i Then
                        list1 = ""
                        For b As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 ' nema potrebe izvrtjeti sve korisnike ponovo i za one kojima su veæ uploadani
                            ' OVAJ DIO JE ZA NOVOULOGIRANE KORISNIKE
                            list1 = list1 & ListBox1.Items.Item(b).ToString + vbCrLf
                        Next
                        Server.Send(i, "@code1841@" & list1)
                    Else
                        Server.Send(i, "@code1841@" & list & "   " & CStr(privSock))             ' OVO JE LAGANI UPDATE POPISA KORISNIKA ZA ONE KOJI SU VEÆ TU
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    list = Nothing
    list1 = Nothing
    new_sock = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub serverSendToAllConnected2(ByVal User As String, ByVal Message As String, Optional ByVal ExceptSock As Integer = -1)
    If isArraySafe(InUse) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To InUse.Length - 1
            If i <> exclude_sock Then
                If Not (i = ExceptSock) Then
                    If InUse(i) Then
                        Server.Send(i, "" & Message)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
#Region "Server Code"
Private Server As socketServer
Private ServerOn As Boolean = False
Private InUse() As Boolean


Private Sub serverLogMessage(ByVal Message As String)
    Delegates.RichTextBoxes.appendText(Me, rtbServer, vbCrLf & Message)
    If Message = "atack" Then
        health = health - 1
        fuel = fuel - 1
        Label6.Text = health
        Label8.Text = fuel
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub serverSendToAllConnected(ByVal User As String, ByVal Message As String, Optional ByVal ExceptSock As Integer = -1)
    If isArraySafe(InUse) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To InUse.Length - 1
            If Not (i = ExceptSock) Then
                If InUse(i) Then
                    Server.Send(i, "Server:  " & Message)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtServeSend_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtServeSend.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Enter) Then
        If Server IsNot Nothing Then
            serverSendToAllConnected("Server", txtServeSend.Text)
            serverLogMessage("Server:  " & txtServeSend.Text)
            txtServeSend.Text = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnStopServe_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStopServe.Click
    If Server Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If ServerOn = False Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Server.stopListen(True)
            serverLogMessage("No longer serving.")
            ServerOn = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
'#################################  FOR LONG IP ADDRESS  -  NEBITNO ######################################
Public Function Dotted2LongIP(ByVal DottedIP As String) As Object
    ' errors will result in a zero value
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim i As Byte, pos As Integer
    Dim PrevPos As Integer, num As Integer

    ' string cruncher
    For i = 1 To 4
        ' Parse the position of the dot
        pos = InStr(PrevPos + 1, DottedIP, ".", 1)

        ' If its past the 4th dot then set pos to the last
        'position + 1

        If i = 4 Then pos = Len(DottedIP) + 1

        ' Parse the number from between the dots

        num = Int(Mid(DottedIP, PrevPos + 1, pos - PrevPos - 1))

        ' Set the previous dot position
        PrevPos = pos

        ' No dot value should ever be larger than 255
        ' Technically it is allowed to be over 255 -it just
        ' rolls over e.g.
        '256 => 0 -note the (4 - i) that's the 
        'proper exponent for this calculation


        Dotted2LongIP = ((num Mod 256) * (256 ^ (4 - i))) + Dotted2LongIP

    Next
    Return Dotted2LongIP
End Function
'#############################################################################################
Private Sub btnServe_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnServe.Click

    If Server Is Nothing Then
        Server = New socketServer()
    Else
        If ServerOn = False Then
            Server = New socketServer()
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    ServerOn = True

    AddHandler Server.IncomingData, AddressOf handleServerIncomingData
    AddHandler Server.Connected, AddressOf handleServerConnected
    AddHandler Server.ConnectionError, AddressOf handleServerConnectionError
    AddHandler Server.ConnectionRefused, AddressOf handleServerConnectionRefused
    AddHandler Server.Disconnected, AddressOf handleServerDisconnected
    AddHandler Server.DisconnectError, AddressOf handleServerDisconnectError
    AddHandler Server.IncomingDataError, AddressOf handleServerIncomingDataError
    AddHandler Server.ListenError, AddressOf handleServerListenError
    AddHandler Server.SendDataError, AddressOf handleServerSendDataError

    ReDim InUse(63)

    Server.Listen(64, txtServePort.Text)

    serverLogMessage("Now serving.")
End Sub

'************************************************************
'Primary Socket Functionality
'************************************************************
Public Sub handleServerIncomingData(ByVal Sock As Integer, ByRef Data As String)
    If InStr(Data, "@code1843@") > 0 And Data.Length > 0 Then
        Data$ = Replace(Data$, "@code1843@", "")
        user = Data
        list = Data
        list1 = Data
        new_sock = Sock
        privSock = Sock
    ElseIf InStr(Data, "@code1842@") > 0 And Data.Length > 0 Then
        Data$ = Replace(Data$, "@code1842@", "")
        disconected = Trim(Mid(Data, 1, Data.Length))
        disconnSock = CStr(Sock)
    ElseIf InStr(Data, "@code1839@") > 0 And Data.Length > 0 Then
        Data$ = Replace(Data$, "@code1839@", "")
        privString = LSet(Data, Data.Length - 2)
        privSock2 = CInt(Trim(Mid(Data, Data.Length - 2)))
        privSock3 = Sock
        sendPriv()
    Else
        If Data.Length > 0 Then
            serverLogMessage(Data)
            sendall = Data
            exclude_sock = Sock
        End If

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub handleServerConnected(ByVal Sock As Integer, ByVal RemoteAddress As String)
    serverLogMessage("Connection from " & RemoteAddress & " to socket space " & Sock & ".")
    InUse(Sock) = True
End Sub

Private Sub handleServerConnectionRefused(ByVal Message As String)
    serverLogMessage(Message)
End Sub

Private Sub handleServerDisconnected(ByVal Sock As Integer)
    serverLogMessage("Socket " & Sock & ":  Disconnected.")
    InUse(Sock) = False
End Sub

'************************************************************
'Functional Error Reporting (Below)
'************************************************************
Private Sub handleServerConnectionError(ByVal Sock As Integer, ByVal Message As String)
    serverLogMessage("Socket " & Sock & ":  " & Message)
End Sub

Private Sub handleServerDisconnectError(ByVal Sock As Integer, ByVal Message As String)
    serverLogMessage("Socket " & Sock & ":  " & Message)
End Sub

Private Sub handleServerIncomingDataError(ByVal Sock As Integer, ByVal Message As String)
    serverLogMessage("Socket " & Sock & ":  " & Message)
End Sub

Private Sub handleServerListenError(ByVal Message As String)
    serverLogMessage("Error:  " & Message)
    ServerOn = False
End Sub

Private Sub handleServerSendDataError(ByVal Sock As Integer, ByVal Message As String)
    serverLogMessage("Socket " & Sock & ":  " & Message)
End Sub
 #End Region

#Region "Client Code"
Dim sr As IO.StringReader
Dim users As String = Nothing
Dim refresh1 As String = Nothing

Dim formNo As String = Nothing
Dim poruka As String = Nothing
Dim br As String = Nothing

Public Sub findForm1()

    If Trim(Mid(My.Forms.Private1.Text, My.Forms.Private1.Text.Length - 2)) = formNo Then
        My.Forms.Private1.RichTextBox1.Text = My.Forms.Private1.RichTextBox1.Text & poruka + vbCrLf

    ElseIf Trim(Mid(My.Forms.Private2.Text, My.Forms.Private2.Text.Length - 2)) = formNo Then
        My.Forms.Private2.RichTextBox1.Text = My.Forms.Private2.RichTextBox1.Text & poruka + vbCrLf
    Else
        If My.Forms.Private1.Visible = False Then
            Dim name As String
            For i As Integer = 1 To poruka.Length
                If Mid(poruka, i, 2) = ": " Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                name = name & Mid(poruka, i, 1)
            Next
            My.Forms.Private1.Show()
            My.Forms.Private1.Text = Trim(name) & "   " & br
            My.Forms.Private1.RichTextBox1.Text = My.Forms.Private1.RichTextBox1.Text & poruka + vbCrLf
        Else
            Dim name As String
            For i As Integer = 1 To poruka.Length
                If Mid(poruka, i, 2) = ": " Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                name = name & Mid(poruka, i, 1)
            Next
            My.Forms.Private2.Show()
            My.Forms.Private2.Text = Trim(name) & "   " & br
            My.Forms.Private2.RichTextBox1.Text = My.Forms.Private2.RichTextBox1.Text & poruka + vbCrLf
        End If
    End If

    formNo = Nothing
    poruka = Nothing

End Sub

Public Sub addUsers()
    sr = New IO.StringReader(users)
    Do Until sr.Peek < 0
        ListBox2.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine)
    Loop
    users = Nothing
End Sub
Public Sub refUsers()
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()
    sr = New IO.StringReader(refresh1)
    Do Until sr.Peek < 0
        ListBox2.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine)
    Loop
    refresh1 = Nothing
End Sub

Private Client As socketClient

Private Sub clientLogMessage(ByVal Message As String)
    Delegates.RichTextBoxes.appendText(Me, rtbClient, vbCrLf & Message)
End Sub

Private Sub btnClientConnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClientConnect.Click
    If InStr(txtClientName.Text, "@code1843@") > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Nickname nesmije sadržavati niz '@code1843@' !")
    ElseIf InStr(txtClientName.Text, " ") > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Nickname nesmije sadržavati razmak !")
    Else

        Client = New socketClient()

        AddHandler Client.Connected, AddressOf handleClientConnected
        AddHandler Client.ConnectionError, AddressOf handleClientConnectionError
        AddHandler Client.Disconnected, AddressOf handleClientDisconnected
        AddHandler Client.DisconnectError, AddressOf handleClientDisconnectError
        AddHandler Client.IncomingData, AddressOf handleClientIncomingData
        AddHandler Client.IncomingDataError, AddressOf handleClientIncomingDataError
        AddHandler Client.SendDataError, AddressOf handleClientSendDataError

        Client.Connect(txtClientIP.Text, txtClientPort.Text)

        '#################################### information about new user ###########################
        If Client.isConnected Then
            Client.Send("@code1843@" & txtClientName.Text)
            clientLogMessage(txtClientName.Text)
            txtClientSend.Text = ""

            txtClientIP.Enabled = False
            txtClientName.Enabled = False
            txtClientPort.Enabled = False
        End If
        '###########################################################################################
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtClientSend_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtClientSend.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Enter) Then
        If Client IsNot Nothing Then
            If Client.isConnected Then
                Client.Send(txtClientName.Text & ":  " & txtClientSend.Text)
                clientLogMessage(txtClientName.Text & ":  " & txtClientSend.Text)
                txtClientSend.Text = ""
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

'************************************************************
'Primary Socket Functionality
'************************************************************
Private Sub handleClientConnected()
    clientLogMessage("Connected!")
End Sub

Private Sub handleClientDisconnected()
    clientLogMessage("Disconnected!")
End Sub

Private Sub handleClientIncomingData(ByRef Data As String)
    If InStr(Data, "@code1841@") > 0 And Data.Length > 0 Then
        Data$ = Replace(Data$, "@code1841@", "")
        users = Data
    ElseIf InStr(Data, "@code1840@") > 0 And Data.Length > 0 Then
        Data$ = Replace(Data$, "@code1840@", "")
        refresh1 = Data
    ElseIf InStr(Data, "@code1847@") > 0 And Data.Length > 0 Then
        Data$ = Replace(Data$, "@code1847@", "")
        formNo = Trim(Mid(Data, Data.Length - 2))
        poruka = Mid(Data, 1, Data.Length - 2)
        br = Trim(Mid(Data, Data.Length - 2))
    Else
        If Data.Length > 0 Then
            clientLogMessage(Data)
        End If
    End If
End Sub


'************************************************************
'Functional Error Reporting (Below)
'************************************************************
Private Sub handleClientConnectionError(ByVal Message As String)
    clientLogMessage(Message)
End Sub

Private Sub handleClientDisconnectError(ByVal Message As String)
    clientLogMessage(Message)
End Sub

Private Sub handleClientIncomingDataError(ByVal Message As String)
    clientLogMessage(Message)
End Sub

Private Sub handleClientSendDataError(ByVal Message As String)
    clientLogMessage(Message)
End Sub
#End Region

Private Sub frmCommunicator_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    End
End Sub

Private Sub btnClientDisconnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClientDisconnect.Click
    Try
        If Client.isConnected Then
            Client.Send("@code1842@" & txtClientName.Text)
            clientLogMessage("Odlogirani ste!")
            txtClientSend.Text = ""
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Client.Disconnect()

    Try
        txtClientIP.Enabled = True
        txtClientName.Enabled = True
        txtClientPort.Enabled = True
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If user <> Nothing Then
        dodaj_korisnika()
        usersUpdate()
    End If
    If list <> Nothing Then

    End If
    If disconected <> Nothing Then
        izbrisi_korisnika()
    End If
    If sendall <> Nothing Then
        senditall()
    End If
    If countListItems > ListBox1.Items.Count Then
        userLeave()
        countListItems -= 1
    End If
    If privSock3 <> Nothing Then
        MsgBox("True")
        sendPriv()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    If users <> Nothing Then
        addUsers()
    End If
    If refresh1 <> Nothing Then
        refUsers()
    End If
    If poruka <> Nothing Then
        findForm1()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtServeSend_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtServeSend.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub rtbServer_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rtbServer.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        If Client.isConnected = True And ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString <> Nothing Then
            If Private1.Visible = False Then
                Private1.Text = ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString
                Private1.Show()
            Else
                Private2.Text = ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString
                Private2.Show()
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
Public Sub privatno1(ByVal br As String)

    Client.Send("@code1839@" & txtClientName.Text & ": " & Private1.TextBox1.Text & "   " & br)

    Private1.TextBox1.Text = ""

End Sub
Public Sub privatno2(ByVal br As String)

    Client.Send("@code1839@" & txtClientName.Text & ": " & Private2.TextBox1.Text & "   " & br)

    Private2.TextBox1.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub frmCommunicator_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label6.Text = health
    Label8.Text = fuel
    Label10.Text = cristaisdequartzo
    Label12.Text = ouro
    Label14.Text = prata
    Label16.Text = diamantes
End Sub
End Class
```

and this is the private 1

```
Public Class Private1

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.Handled = True
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        frmCommunicator.privatno1(Trim(Mid(Me.Text, CInt(Me.Text.Length) - 2)))
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: If you feel the need to post that much code then you haven't spent enough time narrowing down the problem. Also, I have no idea what "the variable of the message received" means.  Please provide a FULL and CLEAR description of the problem and only the RELEVANT code.

Comment: If I understand it correctly you want to broadcast a message to all clients? If so you just have to send a message from the server to every client except the one that sent the initial message. A simple loop through all clients and checking that they're not the sender should be enough. -- I agree with jmcilhinney though, that is too much code to be able to understand the problem.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @VisualVincent On that case how can verify if a word exist a richtextbox

Comment: [**`RichTextBox.Text.Contains("word")`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Please do not put code in comments.  _Edit_ your question and add your code there with any notes about it.

Comment: Running your new code as-is on a `RichTextBox` works without a problem [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzVQm.png). The rest is still too much for us to do anything about.

Answer (score 0):

Tanks Visual Vincent i have solve this code 
This is the working code

```
Public Class frmCommunicator
Dim user As String = Nothing
Dim disconected As String = Nothing
Dim disconnSock As String = Nothing
Dim sendall As String = Nothing
Dim exclude_sock As Integer
Dim new_sock As Integer
Dim privSock As Integer
Dim privSock2 As Integer
Dim privSock3 As Integer
Dim privString As String = Nothing
Dim list As String = Nothing
Dim list1 As String = Nothing
Dim list2 As String = Nothing
Dim countListItems As Integer
Dim health = 100
Dim fuel = 100
Dim cristaisdequartzo = 0
Dim ouro = 0
Dim prata = 0
Dim diamantes = 0

Public Sub sendPriv()

    Server.Send(privSock2, "@code1847@" & privString & "   " & CStr(privSock3))
    Server.Send(privSock3, "@code1847@" & privString & "   " & CStr(privSock2))
    privSock3 = Nothing
    privSock2 = Nothing
    privString = Nothing

End Sub
Public Sub dodaj_korisnika()
    ListBox1.Items.Add(user + "   " + CStr(privSock))
    countListItems += 1
    user = Nothing
End Sub
Public Sub izbrisi_korisnika()
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If ListBox1.Items.Item(i).ToString = disconected & "   " & disconnSock Then
            ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    disconected = Nothing
End Sub
Public Sub senditall()
    serverSendToAllConnected2("", sendall)
    sendall = Nothing
End Sub
Public Sub usersUpdate()
    serverSendToAllConnected3("", sendall)
End Sub
Public Sub userLeave()
    serverSendToAllConnected4("", sendall)
End Sub
Private Sub serverSendToAllConnected4(ByVal User As String, ByVal Message As String, Optional ByVal ExceptSock As Integer = -1)
    If isArraySafe(InUse) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To InUse.Length - 1

            If Not (i = ExceptSock) Then
                If InUse(i) Then

                    list2 = ""
                    For b As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 ' nema potrebe izvrtjeti sve korisnike ponovo i za one kojima su veæ uploadani
                        ' OVAJ DIO JE ZA NOVOULOGIRANE KORISNIKE
                        list2 = list2 & ListBox1.Items.Item(b).ToString + vbCrLf
                    Next
                    Server.Send(i, "@code1840@" & list2)

                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    list2 = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub serverSendToAllConnected3(ByVal User As String, ByVal Message As String, Optional ByVal ExceptSock As Integer = -1)
    If isArraySafe(InUse) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To InUse.Length - 1

            If Not (i = ExceptSock) Then
                If InUse(i) Then
                    If new_sock = i Then
                        list1 = ""
                        For b As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 ' nema potrebe izvrtjeti sve korisnike ponovo i za one kojima su veæ uploadani
                            ' OVAJ DIO JE ZA NOVOULOGIRANE KORISNIKE
                            list1 = list1 & ListBox1.Items.Item(b).ToString + vbCrLf
                        Next
                        Server.Send(i, "@code1841@" & list1)
                    Else
                        Server.Send(i, "@code1841@" & list & "   " & CStr(privSock))             ' OVO JE LAGANI UPDATE POPISA KORISNIKA ZA ONE KOJI SU VEÆ TU
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    list = Nothing
    list1 = Nothing
    new_sock = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub serverSendToAllConnected2(ByVal User As String, ByVal Message As String, Optional ByVal ExceptSock As Integer = -1)
    If isArraySafe(InUse) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To InUse.Length - 1
            If i <> exclude_sock Then
                If Not (i = ExceptSock) Then
                    If InUse(i) Then
                        Server.Send(i, "" & Message)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
#Region "Server Code"
Private Server As socketServer
Private ServerOn As Boolean = False
Private InUse() As Boolean


Private Sub serverLogMessage(ByVal Message As String)
    Delegates.RichTextBoxes.appendText(Me, rtbServer, vbCrLf & Message)

End Sub

Private Sub serverSendToAllConnected(ByVal User As String, ByVal Message As String, Optional ByVal ExceptSock As Integer = -1)
    If isArraySafe(InUse) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To InUse.Length - 1
            If Not (i = ExceptSock) Then
                If InUse(i) Then
                    Server.Send(i, "Server:  " & Message)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtServeSend_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtServeSend.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Enter) Then
        If Server IsNot Nothing Then
            serverSendToAllConnected("Server", txtServeSend.Text)
            serverLogMessage("Server:  " & txtServeSend.Text)
            txtServeSend.Text = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnStopServe_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStopServe.Click
    If Server Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If ServerOn = False Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Server.stopListen(True)
            serverLogMessage("No longer serving.")
            ServerOn = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
'#################################  FOR LONG IP ADDRESS  -  NEBITNO ######################################
Public Function Dotted2LongIP(ByVal DottedIP As String) As Object
    ' errors will result in a zero value
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim i As Byte, pos As Integer
    Dim PrevPos As Integer, num As Integer

    ' string cruncher
    For i = 1 To 4
        ' Parse the position of the dot
        pos = InStr(PrevPos + 1, DottedIP, ".", 1)

        ' If its past the 4th dot then set pos to the last
        'position + 1

        If i = 4 Then pos = Len(DottedIP) + 1

        ' Parse the number from between the dots

        num = Int(Mid(DottedIP, PrevPos + 1, pos - PrevPos - 1))

        ' Set the previous dot position
        PrevPos = pos

        ' No dot value should ever be larger than 255
        ' Technically it is allowed to be over 255 -it just
        ' rolls over e.g.
        '256 => 0 -note the (4 - i) that's the 
        'proper exponent for this calculation


        Dotted2LongIP = ((num Mod 256) * (256 ^ (4 - i))) + Dotted2LongIP

    Next
    Return Dotted2LongIP
End Function
'#############################################################################################
Private Sub btnServe_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnServe.Click

    If Server Is Nothing Then
        Server = New socketServer()
    Else
        If ServerOn = False Then
            Server = New socketServer()
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    ServerOn = True

    AddHandler Server.IncomingData, AddressOf handleServerIncomingData
    AddHandler Server.Connected, AddressOf handleServerConnected
    AddHandler Server.ConnectionError, AddressOf handleServerConnectionError
    AddHandler Server.ConnectionRefused, AddressOf handleServerConnectionRefused
    AddHandler Server.Disconnected, AddressOf handleServerDisconnected
    AddHandler Server.DisconnectError, AddressOf handleServerDisconnectError
    AddHandler Server.IncomingDataError, AddressOf handleServerIncomingDataError
    AddHandler Server.ListenError, AddressOf handleServerListenError
    AddHandler Server.SendDataError, AddressOf handleServerSendDataError

    ReDim InUse(63)

    Server.Listen(64, txtServePort.Text)

    serverLogMessage("Now serving.")
End Sub

'************************************************************
'Primary Socket Functionality
'************************************************************
Public Sub handleServerIncomingData(ByVal Sock As Integer, ByRef Data As String)
    If InStr(Data, "@code1843@") > 0 And Data.Length > 0 Then
        Data$ = Replace(Data$, "@code1843@", "")
        user = Data
        list = Data
        list1 = Data
        new_sock = Sock
        privSock = Sock
    ElseIf InStr(Data, "@code1842@") > 0 And Data.Length > 0 Then
        Data$ = Replace(Data$, "@code1842@", "")
        disconected = Trim(Mid(Data, 1, Data.Length))
        disconnSock = CStr(Sock)
    ElseIf InStr(Data, "@code1839@") > 0 And Data.Length > 0 Then
        Data$ = Replace(Data$, "@code1839@", "")
        privString = LSet(Data, Data.Length - 2)
        privSock2 = CInt(Trim(Mid(Data, Data.Length - 2)))
        privSock3 = Sock
        sendPriv()
    Else
        If Data.Length > 0 Then
            serverLogMessage(Data)
            sendall = Data

            exclude_sock = Sock
        End If

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub handleServerConnected(ByVal Sock As Integer, ByVal RemoteAddress As String)
    serverLogMessage("Connection from " & RemoteAddress & " to socket space " & Sock & ".")
    InUse(Sock) = True
End Sub

Private Sub handleServerConnectionRefused(ByVal Message As String)
    serverLogMessage(Message)
End Sub

Private Sub handleServerDisconnected(ByVal Sock As Integer)
    serverLogMessage("Socket " & Sock & ":  Disconnected.")
    InUse(Sock) = False
End Sub

'************************************************************
'Functional Error Reporting (Below)
'************************************************************
Private Sub handleServerConnectionError(ByVal Sock As Integer, ByVal Message As String)
    serverLogMessage("Socket " & Sock & ":  " & Message)
End Sub

Private Sub handleServerDisconnectError(ByVal Sock As Integer, ByVal Message As String)
    serverLogMessage("Socket " & Sock & ":  " & Message)
End Sub

Private Sub handleServerIncomingDataError(ByVal Sock As Integer, ByVal Message As String)
    serverLogMessage("Socket " & Sock & ":  " & Message)
End Sub

Private Sub handleServerListenError(ByVal Message As String)
    serverLogMessage("Error:  " & Message)
    ServerOn = False
End Sub

Private Sub handleServerSendDataError(ByVal Sock As Integer, ByVal Message As String)
    serverLogMessage("Socket " & Sock & ":  " & Message)
End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Client Code"
Dim sr As IO.StringReader
Dim users As String = Nothing
Dim refresh1 As String = Nothing

Dim formNo As String = Nothing
Dim poruka As String = Nothing
Dim br As String = Nothing

Public Sub findForm1()

    If Trim(Mid(My.Forms.Private1.Text, My.Forms.Private1.Text.Length - 2)) = formNo Then
        My.Forms.Private1.RichTextBox1.Text = My.Forms.Private1.RichTextBox1.Text & poruka + vbCrLf

    ElseIf Trim(Mid(My.Forms.Private2.Text, My.Forms.Private2.Text.Length - 2)) = formNo Then
        My.Forms.Private2.RichTextBox1.Text = My.Forms.Private2.RichTextBox1.Text & poruka + vbCrLf
    Else
        If My.Forms.Private1.Visible = False Then
            Dim name As String
            For i As Integer = 1 To poruka.Length
                If Mid(poruka, i, 2) = ": " Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                name = name & Mid(poruka, i, 1)
            Next
            My.Forms.Private1.Show()
            My.Forms.Private1.Text = Trim(name) & "   " & br
            My.Forms.Private1.RichTextBox1.Text = My.Forms.Private1.RichTextBox1.Text & poruka + vbCrLf
        Else
            Dim name As String
            For i As Integer = 1 To poruka.Length
                If Mid(poruka, i, 2) = ": " Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                name = name & Mid(poruka, i, 1)
            Next
            My.Forms.Private2.Show()
            My.Forms.Private2.Text = Trim(name) & "   " & br
            My.Forms.Private2.RichTextBox1.Text = My.Forms.Private2.RichTextBox1.Text & poruka + vbCrLf
        End If
    End If

    formNo = Nothing
    poruka = Nothing

End Sub

Public Sub addUsers()
    sr = New IO.StringReader(users)
    Do Until sr.Peek < 0
        ListBox2.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine)
    Loop
    users = Nothing
End Sub
Public Sub refUsers()
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()
    sr = New IO.StringReader(refresh1)
    Do Until sr.Peek < 0
        ListBox2.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine)
    Loop
    refresh1 = Nothing
End Sub

Private Client As socketClient

Private Sub clientLogMessage(ByVal Message As String)
    Delegates.RichTextBoxes.appendText(Me, rtbClient, vbCrLf & Message)
End Sub

Private Sub btnClientConnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClientConnect.Click
    If InStr(txtClientName.Text, "@code1843@") > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Nickname nesmije sadržavati niz '@code1843@' !")
    ElseIf InStr(txtClientName.Text, " ") > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Nickname nesmije sadržavati razmak !")
    Else

        Client = New socketClient()

        AddHandler Client.Connected, AddressOf handleClientConnected
        AddHandler Client.ConnectionError, AddressOf handleClientConnectionError
        AddHandler Client.Disconnected, AddressOf handleClientDisconnected
        AddHandler Client.DisconnectError, AddressOf handleClientDisconnectError
        AddHandler Client.IncomingData, AddressOf handleClientIncomingData
        AddHandler Client.IncomingDataError, AddressOf handleClientIncomingDataError
        AddHandler Client.SendDataError, AddressOf handleClientSendDataError

        Client.Connect(txtClientIP.Text, txtClientPort.Text)

        '#################################### information about new user ###########################
        If Client.isConnected Then
            Client.Send("@code1843@" & txtClientName.Text)
            clientLogMessage(txtClientName.Text)
            txtClientSend.Text = ""

            txtClientIP.Enabled = False
            txtClientName.Enabled = False
            txtClientPort.Enabled = False
        End If
        '###########################################################################################
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtClientSend_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtClientSend.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Enter) Then
        If Client IsNot Nothing Then
            If Client.isConnected Then
                Client.Send(txtClientName.Text & ":  " & txtClientSend.Text)
                clientLogMessage(txtClientName.Text & ":  " & txtClientSend.Text)
                txtClientSend.Text = ""
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

'************************************************************
'Primary Socket Functionality
'************************************************************
Private Sub handleClientConnected()
    clientLogMessage("Connected!")
End Sub

Private Sub handleClientDisconnected()
    clientLogMessage("Disconnected!")
End Sub

Private Sub handleClientIncomingData(ByRef Data As String)
    If InStr(Data, "@code1841@") > 0 And Data.Length > 0 Then
        Data$ = Replace(Data$, "@code1841@", "")
        users = Data
    ElseIf InStr(Data, "@code1840@") > 0 And Data.Length > 0 Then
        Data$ = Replace(Data$, "@code1840@", "")
        refresh1 = Data
    ElseIf InStr(Data, "@code1847@") > 0 And Data.Length > 0 Then
        Data$ = Replace(Data$, "@code1847@", "")
        formNo = Trim(Mid(Data, Data.Length - 2))
        poruka = Mid(Data, 1, Data.Length - 2)
        br = Trim(Mid(Data, Data.Length - 2))
    Else
        If Data.Length > 0 Then
            clientLogMessage(Data)
        End If
    End If
End Sub


'************************************************************
'Functional Error Reporting (Below)
'************************************************************
Private Sub handleClientConnectionError(ByVal Message As String)
    clientLogMessage(Message)
End Sub

Private Sub handleClientDisconnectError(ByVal Message As String)
    clientLogMessage(Message)
End Sub

Private Sub handleClientIncomingDataError(ByVal Message As String)
    clientLogMessage(Message)
End Sub

Private Sub handleClientSendDataError(ByVal Message As String)
    clientLogMessage(Message)
End Sub
#End Region

Private Sub frmCommunicator_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    End
End Sub

Private Sub btnClientDisconnect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClientDisconnect.Click
    Try
        If Client.isConnected Then
            Client.Send("@code1842@" & txtClientName.Text)
            clientLogMessage("Odlogirani ste!")
            txtClientSend.Text = ""
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Client.Disconnect()

    Try
        txtClientIP.Enabled = True
        txtClientName.Enabled = True
        txtClientPort.Enabled = True
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If user <> Nothing Then
        dodaj_korisnika()
        usersUpdate()
    End If
    If list <> Nothing Then

    End If
    If disconected <> Nothing Then
        izbrisi_korisnika()
    End If
    If sendall <> Nothing Then
        senditall()
    End If
    If countListItems > ListBox1.Items.Count Then
        userLeave()
        countListItems -= 1
    End If
    If privSock3 <> Nothing Then
        MsgBox("True")
        sendPriv()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    If users <> Nothing Then
        addUsers()
    End If
    If refresh1 <> Nothing Then
        refUsers()
    End If
    If poruka <> Nothing Then
        findForm1()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtServeSend_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtServeSend.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub rtbServer_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rtbServer.TextChanged

    If rtbServer.Text.Contains("atack") Then
        MsgBox("You Are Under Atack")
        health = health - 1
        fuel = fuel - 1
        rtbServer.Clear()

        Label6.Text = health
        Label8.Text = fuel
        Label10.Text = cristaisdequartzo
        Label12.Text = ouro
        Label14.Text = prata
        Label16.Text = diamantes
    End If
    If rtbServer.Text.Contains("health") Then
        MsgBox("You Have Been Health")
        health = health + 10
        rtbServer.Clear()

        Label6.Text = health
        Label8.Text = fuel
        Label10.Text = cristaisdequartzo
        Label12.Text = ouro
        Label14.Text = prata
        Label16.Text = diamantes
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        If Client.isConnected = True And ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString <> Nothing Then
            If Private1.Visible = False Then
                Private1.Text = ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString
                Private1.Show()
            Else
                Private2.Text = ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString
                Private2.Show()
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
Public Sub privatno1(ByVal br As String)

    Client.Send("@code1839@" & txtClientName.Text & ": " & Private1.TextBox1.Text & "   " & br)

    Private1.TextBox1.Text = ""

End Sub
Public Sub privatno2(ByVal br As String)

    Client.Send("@code1839@" & txtClientName.Text & ": " & Private2.TextBox1.Text & "   " & br)

    Private2.TextBox1.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub formatString(ByVal SearchText As String)
    Dim position As Integer = 0
    Dim rtfString As String = LCase(rtbServer.Text)
    Dim cnt As Integer = 0
    Dim isStop As Boolean = False
    While Not isStop
        Dim i As Integer = rtfString.IndexOf(SearchText, cnt)
        If i < 0 Then
            isStop = True
        Else
            rtbServer.Select(i, SearchText.Length)
            rtbServer.SelectionFont = New Font(rtbServer.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
            cnt = i + 1
        End If
    End While
    rtbServer.Select(position, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub frmCommunicator_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    formatString("atack")
    Label6.Text = health
    Label8.Text = fuel
    Label10.Text = cristaisdequartzo
    Label12.Text = ouro
    Label14.Text = prata
    Label16.Text = diamantes

    Dim index As Integer = 0
    While index < rtbServer.Text.LastIndexOf("atack")
        rtbServer.Find("atack", index, rtbServer.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
        rtbServer.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red
        index = rtbServer.Text.IndexOf("atack", index) + 1

        health = health - 1
        fuel = fuel - 1
        rtbServer.Clear()

        Label6.Text = health
        Label8.Text = fuel
        Label10.Text = cristaisdequartzo
        Label12.Text = ouro
        Label14.Text = prata
        Label16.Text = diamantes
    End While

    Dim keywords() As String = {"atack"}
    If keywords.Count(Function(w) rtbServer.Text.ToLower.Contains(w)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox("You Are Under Atack")
        health = health - 1
        fuel = fuel - 1
        rtbServer.Clear()

        Label6.Text = health
        Label8.Text = fuel
        Label10.Text = cristaisdequartzo
        Label12.Text = ouro
        Label14.Text = prata
        Label16.Text = diamantes
    End If

End Sub


End Class
```